# TypeScript Build Error after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 (15.2)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript-typings

In one of my .ts files I defined a namespace that is unfortunately called Request

```
namespace Request {
```

After updating to the latest version of VS (15.2) I get a Build error

```
(Build:Duplicate identifier 'Request')
```

because in `lib.d.ts` there's a interface that is also called Request.

I didn't have this problem in VS (15.1). Any Idea how to solve it without renaming my own Namespace?